# Is there a way to 'auto-select' a tool when a user opens photoeditorsdk?

Tags: android, cordova, photoeditorsdk

I am trying to reduce the number of clicks a user has to go through when using my app.

I see how to configure which tools to show, but I would really like to be able to configure the plugin to automatically open in 'crop mode' at one point. Not, have the user open the app, and then select the lone 'crop tool' I have left available.